# Override permission precedence

Tags: iis, iis-6

When you set permissions on a web app hosted by IIS 6 **denial** does take precedence on the **authorize**. How do I change that behavior?

Here's the pattern I would like to create:

AD Group A: Has full access

AD Group B: Access denied

**NB: Group A can -is- contained by group B**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do such!

Denial takes always precedence! You have to organize your groups differently!